# Меню с подменю и отображение содержимого подменю

Tags: django, menu

Файл models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

from django.utils.text import slugify


# Модель подкатегорий
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    maincategory = models.ForeignKey('MainCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:ProductListByCategory', args=[self.slug])


#Модель главных категорий
class MainCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.slug, allow_unicode=True)
        # при сохранении сам заполнит SLUG
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


# Модель продукта
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', verbose_name="Категория", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="Название")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name="Изображение товара")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Описание")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Цена")
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="На складе")
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Доступен")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        index_together = [
            ['id', 'slug']
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:ProductDetail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Файл urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'shop'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductList, name='ProductList'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.ProductList, name='ProductListByCategory'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.ProductDetail, name='ProductDetail'),
]
```

Файл views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response

from .models import Category, Product, MainCategory
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm


# Страница с товарами
def ProductList(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    #subcategory = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    #subcategories = SubCategory.objjects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products,
    })



# Страница товара без корзины
def ProductDetail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html', {'product': product})
```

Шаблон страницы

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
  {{ product.name }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="product-detail">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no-image.jpg"%}{% endif %}" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
      <h2><a href="{{ product.category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.category }}</a></h2>
      <p class="price">{{ product.price }} руб.</p>
      <form action="{% url "cart:CartAdd" product.id %}" method="post">
          {{ cart_product_form }}
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="submit" value="Добавить в корзину">
      </form>
      <span>
        {{ product.description | linebreaks}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

В файл models.py добавил "Модель главных категорий"
Вопрос что нужно изменить в views.py , urls.py и шаблоне, чтобы отображались главные категории, в них подкатегории а затем сами товары

Comment: просто циклом перебераешь категории, затем вложенным циклом подкатегории и ещё одним вложенным - товары.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 
Как это во views.py отразить, пока не принимаются данные от MainCategory

Comment: это в шаблоне нужно делать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это

**views**

```
def ProductList(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    #subcategory = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    #subcategories = SubCategory.objjects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    main_categories = MainCategory.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products,
        'main_categories': main_categories
    })
```

**shop/product/list.html**

```
{% for cat in main_categories %}
  {{ cat }}
  {% for subcat in cat.category_set.all %}
  __{{ subcat }}
    {% for prod in subcat.product_set.all %}
      ____{{ prod }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Отображает пустой <ul>